# Has MongoDB Improved Its Algorithms for Reusing Empty Space?

Tags: mongodb

I'm going through "MongoDB, The Definitive Guide, 2nd edition", and the author states: "As of this writing, MongoDB is not great at reusing empty space, so moving documents
around a lot can result in large swaths of empty data file... If your schema requires lots of moves or lots of churn through inserts and deletes, you
can improve disk reuse by using the `usePowerOf2Sizes` option".

This book was written when MongoDB was version 2.4, while today its version 3.4. After going through a major version update, i'm curious if Mongo has made revisions to where the usage of `usePowerOf2Sizes` option is still necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, MongoDB has included a new storage engine WiredTiger which is great improvement and doesn't store the data like earlier MMapV1 used to store where there was predefined size and when the size increased it applies twice the size, kind of how arraylist works in Java.

However MongoDB does provide a [compact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/) command to reclaim the empty spaces, similar to memory defragmentation. Really useful when working with MMapV1 and have collection with millions of documents.